# google cloud mailer api 429 error Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)

Tags: gmail-api

i get the below error randomly when using the google mailer api to send emails using the wordpress post smtp plugin, i can replicate the email if i send 200 bulk emails, but checking the peak it doesnt get near the peak, any failed emails i have to re-send

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 429,
> "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
> }
> ],
> "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
> }
> }

Answer (score 0):

rateLimitExceeded is flood protection your going to fast slow your code down.

Comment: thanks for your response, how can i enable logging to see all events being triggered against my api?
additionally, this problem im having can occur before i trigger the script to send out 50 emails so it doesnt seem to be happening when its being 'flooded' unless something else is using my api keys which doesnt make sense

Comment: have you checked what your current quota is on google cloud console for the gmail api?

Comment: shows only 141 requests for this api, likely for the whole day, we dont use it much

the quotas are 15,000 requests per minute per user and another 1,200,000 Queries per minute , our usage is only 0.02% so no where near the limit so doesnt make sense why im getting this error..

Comment: problem fixed for now after creating a new api credential .. not sure how that would fix the problem but all good

Comment: just got the error happen again today, it seems to happen only sometimes, when we send a burst of emails using the post smtp wordpress plugin

{ "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).", "errors": [ { "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).", "domain": "global", "reason": "rateLimitExceeded" } ], "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" } }

Comment: i still get the problem every so often, we are the only ones using this api